# SVN for managing mp3 on multiple devies

Tags: mp3, subversion

i need an easy way to "update my local music copy" on each device. (folders and mp3 files, some txt files)

is there a better way than use SVN for this? can someone recommend a software for this maybe?

thanks

Comment: SVN does a horrid job on this as it does not handle binary files well at all. Git handles binaries a lot better than SVN but is still not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

SVN or any other VCS tool is the worst choice for syncing remote copies of *anything*. Just because it's versioning tool, not backup or cloud storage

**Any cloud solution** for files will be more easy, more natural and more effective way of solving your problem (OneDrive, GoogleDrive, DropBox, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/). Here is a quote from [its website](https://nextcloud.com/athome/):

> Nextcloud puts your data at your fingertips, under your control. Store your documents, calendar, contacts and photos on a server at home, at one of our providers or in a data center you trust.

This [introduction](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/15/admin_manual/#videos-and-blogs) page should help to get a first impression about what it is all about.